# How to check if multiple characters are in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of combinations (say 5 digit pin number) and want to take only the ones that have 1,2 and 3 in them. Looked around here but didnt seem to find any for some reason.

```
if 1 in combination and 2 in combination and 3 in combination:
```

This seems to work, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way since mine is quite ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `combination` is a set you can perform a subset check:

```
if {1, 2, 3} <= combination:
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
if all(x in combination for x in (1, 2, 3)):
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `(1, 2, 3)` instead of `[1, 2, 3]` in that `all` call?

Comment: Not really. `(1, 2, 3)` and `[1, 2, 3]` are functionally equivalent in this context. Some people prefer `()` to signal the numbers are read-only; others prefer the look of `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `mobination` to string, and check the `intersaction` in `set`.

```
>>> combination = '456'
>>> needed = '123'
>>> set(needed) & set(combination)
set([])
>>> combination = '156'
>>> set(needed) & set(combination)
set(['1'])
```

If you get value return from `intersection` then your needed value is in `combination`.